# Are keys and values of %INC platform-dependent or not?

Tags: perl, cross-platform, perlvar

I'd like to get the full filename of an included module. Consider this code:

```
package MyTest;

my $path = join '/', split /::/, __PACKAGE__;
$path .= ".pm";

print "$INC{$path}\n";

1;
```

---

```
$ perl -Ipath/to/module -MMyTest -e0
path/to/module/MyTest.pm
```

Will it work on all platforms?

`perlvar`

> The hash `%INC` contains entries for
>   each filename included via the `do`,
>   `require`, or `use`operators. The key
>   is the filename you specified (with
>   module names converted to pathnames),
>   and the value is the location of the
>   file found.

Are these keys platform-dependent or not? Should I use `File::Spec` or what? At least ActivePerl on win32 uses `/` instead of `\`.

**Update:** What about `%INC` values? Are they platform-dependent?

Comment: What do you want to do with the path? Please provide more context!

Comment: Say, I want to include more modules from there.

Answer (score 2):

Given that it's a standard module, go with the approach from [Module::Loaded](http://perldoc.perl.org/Module/Loaded.html):

```
sub is_loaded (*) { 
    my $pm      = shift;
    my $file    = __PACKAGE__->_pm_to_file( $pm ) or return;

    return $INC{$file} if exists $INC{$file};

    return;
}

sub _pm_to_file {
    my $pkg = shift;
    my $pm  = shift or return;

    my $file = join '/', split '::', $pm;
    $file .= '.pm';

    return $file;
}
```

Comment: Actually this is the very same code I wrote. And it seems, that this module works on most platforms. Thank you. http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/M/Module-Loaded.html#Module-Loaded-0.06 Can you say anything about portability of `%INC` values?

Comment: @codeholic Which platforms do you have in mind? Remember that `/` is a valid path separator on Win32, and much nicer looking than obnoxious double-backwhacks. Don't let the Windows command shell's geb0rken *interface* mislead you.

Comment: I want to make as cross-platform code as possible, since I'm looking forward to post it on CPAN finally.

Comment: / is not a valid seperator on VMS (at least at an OS level - Perl can handle these and convert to the OS format).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reasonably robust implementation that will also work for modules that haven't been loaded yet.

```
use File::Find;
use File::Spec;

sub pkg2path (*) {
    my $file = join '[\\\/:]' =>
               map  "\Q$_"    =>
               split /::|'/   => "$_[0].pm";            # '

    /$file$/ and return File::Spec->rel2abs( $INC{$_} )
        for keys %INC;

    # omit the rest to only find loaded modules

    my $path; find {
        no_chdir => 1,
        wanted   => sub {
            $path = $_ and goto found if /$file$/
        }
    } => @INC;

    found: File::Spec->rel2abs($path or return)
}

say pkg2path Benchmark;
say pkg2path Devel::Trace;
```

Comment: The same code is written better in `Module::Find`. But it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: the first line of pkg2path has your answer. no, its not safe to trust that the entries in %INC will have a particular pattern (if only because %INC is user writable). That's why I wrote the regex builder (which is not found in Module::Find, and it doesn't even use %INC btw). Nice to know you appreciate the few people that took the time to think about and answer your question